# Is it possible to combine spells?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

Slightly related to the "[What spell inflates Aunt Marge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13114/what-spell-inflates-aunt-marge)?" question.
**Can spells be combined to create the effect of casting two spells** (but without the time lag involved in pronouncing a long name and doing the "swish and flick" gesture twice)?
Would this be creating a new spell?

Does anyone remember anything in the books that could possibly be ascribed to a character performing two spells together? (Not two characters aiming different spells at the same target at the same time.)

[Slightly off on a tangent too, but would it be possible for a wizard to use two wands at the same time?]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `Can spells be combined to create the effect of casting two spells (but without the time lag involved in pronouncing a long name and doing the "swish and flick" gesture twice)? Would this be creating a new spell?`

I'm not sure if you want to count it, but Bat-Bogey Hex seems to fit the bill. It does 3 spells at once: Turns someone's bogeys into bats (some sort of transfiguration spell); causes the bats to be enlarged (effect of *Engorgio*); and sets them attacking the target (effect of *Oppugno*).

---

- `would it be possible for a wizard to use two wands at the same time`

Yes, though the example was NOT not to fire off two different spells. From *DH*, CH 23:

> As Ron ran to pull Hermione out of the wreckage, Harry took
>   the chance: He leapt over an armchair and **wrested the three wands
>   from Draco’s grip, pointed all of them at Greyback, and yelled,
>   “Stupefy!” The werewolf was lifted off his feet by the triple spell**,
>   flew up to the ceiling and then smashed to the ground.

Comment: great work DVK, answered everything. I was thinking that sectumsepra would be one of the combined spells, what are your thoughts on that?

Comment: "Bogeys" is the UK version of "boogers" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booger

Comment: @DVK Hahaha! Good one!